# Date.UTC configurar zona horaria javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Estoy  introduciendo datos a un grafico, lo que sucede que al traer los datos y introducirlos en la función Date.UTC este me agrega un mes mas entregándome una fecha erronea ejemplo:

```
Date.UTC(parseInt(val.year),parseInt(val.month),parseInt(val.day), parseInt(val.hour), parseInt(val.min));

Date.UTC(parseInt(2018),parseInt(10),parseInt(08), parseInt(10), parseInt(17));
```

Me devuelve  noviembre 08, 2018 siendo que es octubre 8

```
he intentado hacer esto sin resultados: 

 new Date().toLocaleString('es-CL', { timeZone: 'America/Santiago' })
```

gracias por su atención , estaré atento a tus respuestas saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los meses en Data.UTC empiezan en 0, no en 1, por lo que van de 0 (enero) a 11 (diciembre). Seguramente tu problema es que alimentas la función pensando en meses de 1 a 12.

Puedes verlo en la doc de la función [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/UTC):

> mes
>
> Un entero entre 0 y 11 que representa al mes.

Comment: Exactamente era la conclusión que había llegado , lo que tube que hacer es restar 1 al mes y introducirlo en la función quizas no es lo mas recomendable pero no encuentro una función en dateformat mysql que me realize esta tarea gracias por responder.

Comment: Creo que es bastante típico lo de andar sumando/restando uno cuando enredas con fechas en JS (porque al leer el mes también te lo da de 0 a 11).